# Wordpress not open without VPN

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, hosting, backend

My Wordpress Website not open except with using VPN. It just keep loading till the browser says :"This site can not be reached." I even checked with other ISP internet but the problem is still remained. I have other sites in my host and they work fine but the Wordpress one not open. The only thing that appears is the page title in browser's tab.

Comment: Hi there! Your question isn't programming-related (more like network-related actually) so it really doesn't belong here. You may want to try asking here instead: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your IP is blocked by your site either in your WordPress settings or from hosting side.

First check blocked IPs from WordPress Admin Settings or check its (.htaccess) on in your site's database.